# How to add Active Directory module in PowerShell in Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've installed Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10 Technical Preview (January 2015) but no dice. Anybody knows how to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm using Win 10 Pro

Comment: After installing RSAT, did you also activate the desired Windows features?

Comment: It's currenlty not possible in Win 10.

However this should work:
http://mikefrobbins.com/2015/08/05/using-powershell-for-remote-server-administration-in-windows-10-rtm-without-the-rsat-tools/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSAT tools for the release build of Windows 10 aren't out yet.

It's [expected](https://twitter.com/GabeAul/status/630159064203309056) sometime this month, alongside Tech Preview 3 of Server 2016.

Once it's out, install and enable as you normally would.

For now, you could always spin up a Windows 8 VM (using the included Hyper-V feature?) and import a remote PowerShell session from that.

Something along the lines of:

```
$RsatSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName Win8VM # Maybe include -credential or -authentication
Import-PSSession -Session $RsatSession -Module ActiveDirectory,(Any other RSAT Modules you want)
```

*Note: I haven't tested this myself. I'm holding off on upgrading my workstation until the tools are out.*

Comment: In the meantime, they are available now: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520